# Some basic questions about MethodHandle API

Tags: java, reflection, java-7

How can I obtain all declared method through `MethodHandles.lookup()`? How can I obtain all declared fields?

What is difference betweeen `MethodHandle.invoke()`, `MethodHandle.invokeExact()` and `MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments()`

Also, I will be appreciate for tutorial about using MethodHandle API for **Java devloper**. I emphasize, I am programming on statically typed language plain old Java and I am not JVM developer, particularly I am not interesting with whole byte-code crap (invokedynamic). I want to figure out how can I use this new API instead of Java Core API.

**EDITED-2:**

@Glen Best below provided some refferences I want to provide only one http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20130102?pg=52&search_term=methodhandle&doc_id=-1#pg50 This is exactly what I was looking for. I figured out that actually there some new vocabalry.. For example, by *target* is actually meant MethodHandle (and not object to make dispatch upon) and *call site* is actually code that "invokes" "function pointer" aka MethodHandle. Also it is essential to understand that MethodHandle API is **not replacement for** Core Reflection API rather than *suplement* it. For example, you can't "discover" all methods with MethodHandle you need Core Reflection API. But when you "find" you desired method you can switch to MethodHandle and for example, bound some its parameters or "change" (adapt) it's signature to varargs for example.

**EDITED:**

I am still trying to figure out answer. I wrote some tests that I want to share with all.

```
package alexander.berkovich;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MethodHandlerCleanTest {

    public static MethodHandles.Lookup lookup;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void asetUp(){
        lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    }

    public static class Check {
        public void primitive(final int i){
        }
        public void wrapper(final Integer i){
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrimitive() throws Throwable {
        Check check = new Check();

        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class, int.class);

        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(Check.class, "primitive", type);
        mh.invokeWithArguments(check, 1);
        mh.invoke(check, (short)2);
        mh.invoke(check, Integer.valueOf(3));

        Method method = Check.class.getMethod("primitive", int.class);
        method.invoke(check, (short)20);
        method.invoke(check, Integer.valueOf(21));

    }

    @Test
    public void testWrapper() throws Throwable {
        Check check = new Check();

        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class, Integer.class);

        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(Check.class, "wrapper", type);
        mh.invoke(check, 2);

        Method method = Check.class.getMethod("wrapper", Integer.class);
        method.invoke(check, 20);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static class StaticInnerClass {

        public static String staticName;
        public String name;


        public void foo(){}

        public static void staticFoo(){}

    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticInnerClassStaticField() throws Throwable {
        MethodHandle mhSet = lookup.findStaticSetter(StaticInnerClass.class, "staticName", String.class);
        String expected = "mama";
        mhSet.invoke(expected);

        MethodHandle mhGet = lookup.findStaticGetter(StaticInnerClass.class, "staticName", String.class);
        Object obj = mhGet.invoke();
        String value = (String)obj;
        assertSame(expected, value);

    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticInnerClassField() throws Throwable {
        StaticInnerClass sut = new StaticInnerClass();
        Field f = StaticInnerClass.class.getDeclaredField("name");
        MethodHandle mhSetUnreflect = lookup.unreflectSetter(f); 
        String expectedUnreflect = "unreflect";
        mhSetUnreflect.invoke(sut, expectedUnreflect);


        MethodHandle mhSet = lookup.findSetter(StaticInnerClass.class, "name", String.class);
        String expected = "mama";
        mhSet.invoke(sut, expected);

        MethodHandle mhGet = lookup.findGetter(StaticInnerClass.class, "name", String.class);
        Object obj = mhGet.invoke(sut);
        String value = (String)obj;
        assertSame(expected, value);

    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticInnerClassConstructor() throws Throwable {
        StaticInnerClass sut = new StaticInnerClass();
        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class);
        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findConstructor(StaticInnerClass.class, type);
        mh.invoke();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticInnerClassMethod() throws Throwable {
        StaticInnerClass sut = new StaticInnerClass();
        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class);
        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(StaticInnerClass.class, "foo", type);
        mh.invoke(sut);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticInnerClassStaticMethod() throws Throwable {
        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class);
        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findStatic(StaticInnerClass.class, "staticFoo", type);
        mh.invoke();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private class InnerClass {
        public String name;

        public void foo(){}

    }
    @Test
    public void testInnerClassField() throws Throwable {
        InnerClass sut = new InnerClass();
        MethodHandle mhSet = lookup.findSetter(InnerClass.class, "name", String.class);
        String expected = "mama";
        mhSet.invoke(sut, expected);

        MethodHandle mhGet = lookup.findGetter(InnerClass.class, "name", String.class);
        Object obj = mhGet.invoke(sut);
        String value = (String)obj;
        assertSame(expected, value);

    }


    @Test
    public void testInnerClassConstructor() throws Throwable {
        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class, MethodHandlerCleanTest.class);

        //default constructor is private
        Field field = MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredField("IMPL_LOOKUP");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        MethodHandles.Lookup trustedLookup = (MethodHandles.Lookup) 
                field
                .get(null);

        MethodHandle mh = trustedLookup.findConstructor(InnerClass.class, type);
        mh.invoke(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testInnerClassMethod() throws Throwable {
        InnerClass sut = new InnerClass();
        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class);
        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(InnerClass.class, "foo", type);
        mh.invoke(sut);
    }
```

}

Comment: [Performance comparisons (with examples)](http://java.dzone.com/articles/methodhandle-performance-java), [A glimpse at MethodHandle and its usage](http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=191) and/or [MethodHandle vs. Reflection benchmark](http://www.jroller.com/thnagy/entry/methodhandle_vs_reflection_benchmark) - these are the top few Google hits. PS- Thanks for an interesting read :D; PPS- I also noticed some examples in the JavaDocs under `MethodHandle`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> *How can I obtain all declared method through MethodHandles.lookup()? How can I obtain all declared fields?*

Think of java.lang.invoke as a (fast performing) extension to reflection (java.lang.reflect) - i.e. "invoke" classes are dependent upon "reflection" classes.

- You obtain reference to all methods/constructors/fields via reflection (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect):

  ```
  java.lang.Class<?> someClass = ...;  // obtain a Class somehow

  // Returns all constructors/methods/fields declared in class, 
  // whether public/protected/package/private, 
  // but does NOT include definitions from any ancestors:

  java.lang.reflect.Constructor<?>[] declaredConstructors = someClass.getDeclaredConstructors();
  java.lang.reflect.Method[] declaredMethods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
  java.lang.reflect.Field[] declaredFields   = someClass.getDeclaredFields();

  // Returns all constructors/methods/fields declared as public members 
  // in the class AND all ancestors: 

  java.lang.reflect.Constructor<?>[] publicInheritedConstructors = someClass.getConstructors();
  java.lang.reflect.Method[] publicInheritedMethods = someClass.getMethods();
  java.lang.reflect.Field[] publicInheritedFields   = someClass.getFields();
  ```
- You convert them to MethodHandles via java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup:

  ```
  java.lang.invoke.MethodType mt; 
  java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle mh;
  java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();

  // process methods
  for (java.lang.reflect.Method method: declaredMethods) {
      mh = lookup.unreflect(method);

      // can call mh.invokeExact (requiring first parameter to be the class' 
      // object instance upon which the method will be invoked, followed by 
      // the methodparameter types, with an exact match parameter and return 
      // types) or
      // mh.invoke/invokeWithArguments (requiring first parameter to be the 
      // class' object instance upon which the method will be invoked, 
      // followed by the method parameter types, with compatible conversions 
      // performed on input/output types)
  }

  // process constructors
  for (java.lang.reflect.Constructor<?> constructor: declaredConstructors) {
      mh = lookup.unreflectConstructor(constructor);

      // can call mh.invokeExact or
      // mh.invoke/invokeWithArguments 
  }

  // process field setters
  for (java.lang.reflect.Field field: declaredFields) {
      mh = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);

      // can call mh.invokeExact or
      // mh.invoke/invokeWithArguments 
  }

  // process field getters
  for (java.lang.reflect.Field field: declaredFields) {
      mh = lookup.unreflectGetter(field);

      // can call mh.invokeExact or
      // mh.invoke/invokeWithArguments 
  }
  ```
- You can determine if the signature of methods/constructors/fields via java.lang.reflect:

  ```
  // If generics involved in method signature:
  Type[] paramTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes(); 
  Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType(); 
  // Note: if Class is non-static inner class, first parameter of 
  // getGenericParameterTypes() is the enclosing class

  // If no generics involved in method signature:
  Class<?>[] paramTypes = declaredMethod.getParameterTypes(); 
  Class<?> returnType = declaredMethod.getReturnType(); 
  // Note: if Class is non-static inner class, first parameter of 
  // getParameterTypes() is the enclosing class

  // Same method calls for declaredConstructor
  ```
- You can determine if the methods/constructors/fields are static via java.lang.reflect:

  ```
  int modifiers = method.getModifiers();  // same method for constructor/field
  boolean isStatic = java.lang.Modifier.isStatic(modifiers);
  ```

> *What is difference betweeen MethodHandle.invoke(), MethodHandle.invokeExact() and MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments()?*

- see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object...%29
- If the `MethodHandle` is for a non-static method, the first parameter provided to these methods is an instance of the `Class` which declares the method.  The method is invoked on this instance of the class (or on the Class itself for static methods).  If the `Class` is a non-static inner class, the second parameter is an instance of the enclosing/declaring class.  The subsequent parameters are the method signature parameters, in order.
- **`invokeExact`** does not do automatic compatible type conversion on input parameters.  It requires parameter values (or parameter expressions) to be an exact type match to the method signature, with each parameter provided as a separate argument OR all arguments provided together as an array (signature: `Object invokeExact(Object... args)`).
- **`invoke`** requires the parameter values (or parameter expressions) to be type compatible match to the method signature - automatic type conversions are performed, with each parameter provided as a separate argument OR all arguments provided together as an array  (signature: Object invoke(Object... args))
- **`invokeWithArguments`** requires the parameter values (or parameter expressions) to be type compatible match to the method signature - automatic type conversions are performed, with each parameter provided within a List (signature: `Object invokeWithArguments(List<?> arguments)`)

> *I will be appreciate for tutorial about using MethodHandle API for Java devloper*

There's not much out there, unfortunately.  You could try the following.  Hopefully, I've given enough info above :^)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html
   http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=191
   http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20130102?pg=52&search_term=methodhandle&doc_id=-1#pg50
   [http://www.amazon.com/Well-Grounded-Java-Developer-techniques-programming/dp/1617290068](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290068)

Comment: `OR all arguments provided together as an array` - I don't believe this is correct. Neither `invoke` nor `invokeExact` seem to accept an array that contains the arguments (the varargs is very misleading in this regard). Only `invokeWithArguments` will accept arguments provided as an array and then behaves very similar to `Method#invoke(Object, Obect...)`.

Comment: Also strictly speaking `"invoke" classes are dependent upon "reflection" classes` is not entirely correct. The `invokeExact` and `invoke` methods are *native* methods annotated with the internal `@PolymorphicSignature` annotation,  `which distinguishes (to the Java compiler) those methods which are signature polymorphic` (PolymorphicSignature javadoc). See also: [Signature polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#sigpoly). Class `MethodHandle` does not depend on any class inside the `java.lang.reflect` package.

Comment: “If the Class is a non-static inner class, the second parameter is an instance of the enclosing/declaring class.” This is wrong, the second argument is where the normal args  start.

Answer (score 13):

> What is difference betweeen MethodHandle.invoke(), MethodHandle.invokeExact() and MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments()

Since I also struggled with this, I decided to revisit this question and write an example that shows exactly what the semantic differences between these methods are.

The major differences are:

1. `invokeExact` **only** accepts *exact* arguments and return types, and does **not** accept arguments as an array. Calling e.g. method signature `(Integer,Integer)Integer` with an `int` argument is not allowed, but also calling it with an `Object` argument is not allowed, even if the object is actually of type Integer -  the *compiletime* type of the argument must be of class Integer, not the runtime instance:

   ```
   Object arg = 1; Object[] args = {1,1};
   Integer i = (Integer)handle.invokeExact(1,1); // OK
   Object o = handle.invokeExact(arg,arg); // ERROR
   handle.invokeExact(args); // ERROR
   ```

---

2. `invoke` automatically converts argument types and return types and also converts between primitive types and the corresponding wrapper classes. But it does also **not** accept arguments as an array. E.g. for method signature `(Integer,Integer)Integer`:

   ```
   Object arg = 1; Object[] args = {1,1};
   Integer i = (Integer)handle.invoke(1,1); // OK
   Object o = handle.invoke(arg,arg); // OK!
   o = handle.invoke(args); // ERROR
   ```

---

3. `invokeWithArguments` removes all these restrictions and works very similar to `Method#invoke` - you can also supply an array (or a `java.util.List`) as an argument (but this flexibility comes with a *huge* performance penalty). E.g. for method signature `(Integer,Integer)Integer`:

   ```
   Object arg = 1; Object[] args = {1,1};
   Integer i = (Integer)handle.invokeWithArguments(1,1); // OK
   Object o = handle.invokeWithArguments(arg,arg); // OK
   o = handle.invokeWithArguments(args); // OK!
   ```

---

Here a complete example:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MethodHandleTest {

    public static class TestClass{
        public int test(int a, Integer b){
            return a+b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
        Method method = TestClass.class.getMethod("test", int.class, Integer.class);
        MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(method).bindTo(new TestClass());

        int arg_int = 1;
        Integer argInteger = 1;

        Object[] argArray = {1,1};

        //----------------------------
        // MethodHandle#invokeExact() 
        //----------------------------

        // ONLY an exact invocation is allowed for invokeExact:
        int result = (int) handle.invokeExact(arg_int, argInteger); 

        // inexact first argument type -> throws WrongMethodTypeException - "expected (int,Integer)int but found (Integer,Integer)int"
        Exception e = null;
        try {
            result = (int) handle.invokeExact(argInteger,argInteger);
        } catch (WrongMethodTypeException ex) {
            e = ex;
        }
        assert e != null;
        e = null;

        // inexact return type -> throws WrongMethodTypeException - "expected (int,Integer)int but found (int,Integer)Integer"
        try {
            result = (Integer) handle.invokeExact(arg_int,argInteger);
        } catch (WrongMethodTypeException ex) {
            e = ex;
        }
        assert e != null;
        e = null;

        // inexact return type -> throws WrongMethodTypeException - "expected (int,Integer)int but found (int,Integer)Object"
        try {
            Object o = handle.invokeExact(arg_int,argInteger);
        } catch (WrongMethodTypeException ex) {
            e = ex;
        }
        assert e != null;
        e = null;

        // "argObject" is ALSO NOT OK! - the compile time type of the argument must be of class Integer, not the runtime instance!
        // -> throws WrongMethodTypeException - "expected (int,Integer)int but found (int,Object)int"
        Object argObject = argInteger;
        try {
            result = (int) handle.invokeExact(arg_int,argObject);
        } catch (WrongMethodTypeException ex) {
            e = ex;
        }
        assert e != null;
        e = null;

        // Array of the arguments NOT allowed -> throws WrongMethodTypeException - "expected (int,Integer)int but found (Object[])int"
        try {
            result = (int) handle.invokeExact(argArray);
        } catch (WrongMethodTypeException ex) {
            e = ex;
        }
        assert e != null;
        e = null;

        // But explicit cast of first or second argument is OK
        result = (int) handle.invokeExact((int)argInteger,argInteger);
        result = (int) handle.invokeExact(arg_int,(Integer)arg_int);

        //-----------------------
        // MethodHandle#invoke() 
        //-----------------------

        // invoke() with exact types - OK -> actually calls invokeExact() behind the scenes
        result = (int) handle.invoke(arg_int, argInteger);

        // implicit conversion of inexact arguments and return type -> OK!
        result = (Integer) handle.invoke(argInteger,argInteger); 

        // Object arguments or return type is OK!
        Object o = handle.invoke(argObject,argObject);

        // Array of the arguments NOT allowed -> throws WrongMethodTypeException - "cannot convert MethodHandle(int,Integer)int to (Object[])int"
        try {
            result = (int) handle.invoke(argArray);
        } catch (WrongMethodTypeException ex) {
            e = ex;
        }
        assert e != null;
        e = null;

        //------------------------------------
        // MethodHandle#invokeWithArguments() 
        //------------------------------------

        // invoke() with exact types - OK
        result = (int) handle.invokeWithArguments(arg_int,arg_int);

        // implicit conversion of inexact arguments and return type -> OK
        result = (Integer) handle.invokeWithArguments(argInteger,argInteger); 

        // Object arguments or return type is OK!
        o = handle.invoke(argObject,argObject);

        // Array of the arguments -> OK
        result = (int) handle.invokeWithArguments(argArray);

        // List of arguments possible -> same as calling invokeWithArguments(list.toArray())
        result = (int) handle.invokeWithArguments(Arrays.asList(argArray));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Balder said both calls `invoke` and `invokeExact` do not accept arguments passed in as an array. (However, they do accept array arguments.)

```
int[] args = {1,1};

// handle for Math.addExact(int, int)
Object o = handle.invokeExact(1,1); // OK
Object o = handle.invoke(1,1); // OK
Object o = handle.invokeExact(args); // ERROR
Object o = handle.invoke(args); // ERROR
```

The error is always a wrong type exception:

```
java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(int, int)int to (Object[])int
```

So it does not unpack the array. But passing in an array where it is required works:

```
// handle for Arrays.sort(int[]) 
handle.invokeExact(args); // OK
handle.invoke(args); // OK
```

As Balder said, implementing the desired behavior with `invokeWithArguments()` may incur a quite substantial overhead.

In order to get the desired behavior for unpacking argument lists as known from varargs, one has to turn the handle into a spreader:

```
 // handle for Math.addExact(int, int)
 handle = handle.asSpreader(int[].class, 2);
 handle.invokeExact(args); // OK
 handle.invoke(args); // OK
```

Of course, the same functionality as for explicit argument passing accounts again when the array is defined to be generic:

```
 Object[] args = new Object[]{1,1};
 // handle for Math.addExact(int, int)
 handle = handle.asSpreader(int[].class, 2);
 handle.invokeExact(args); // ERROR
 handle.invoke(args); // OK
```

I have not conducted any performance comparison between the calls. For those interested, it is quite straight forward to extend this benchmark:
http://rick-hightower.blogspot.de/2013/10/java-invoke-dynamic-examples-java-7.html

#### Details:

Essentially `invokeWithArguments` does similar things but does so for every call:

```
 public Object invokeWithArguments(Object... arguments) throws Throwable {
    MethodType invocationType = MethodType.genericMethodType(arguments == null ? 0 : arguments.length);
    return invocationType.invokers().spreadInvoker(0).invokeExact(asType(invocationType), arguments);
}
```

So creating a spreader once and reusing it, will most likely yield similar performance as `invoke` and `invokeExact`.